# How to read out the 2nd layer in UDP Ethernet communication under windows in c++ while multi-casting and using IPv6?

Tags: c, udp, ipv6, multicast, winsock2

I am messing around with communication over Ethernet. I want to program a server, that binds to a port and receives incoming massages. I want to use IPv6 and catch the UDP massage from an multi-cast. I am also on a windows machine and using winsock2.

The code below (boiled down to the basics) already works and functions in a way i want it to. I am able to receive the messages send by an other application. I can read out the UDP header and payload.

However, now i am interested in also reading out the IP header and also the 2nd Layer of the TCP/IP model containing the MAC address.

**Question**

How to modify the code to not only get the UDP header but also the IP header and 2nd Layer?

**My Problem**

I am new to socket programming and i am having trouble: Changing the `IPPROTO_UDP` to `IPPROTO_RAW` only yields in the problem, that I am not able to receive any massages by `recvfrom()`, while no setup calls creates an error (not given in code below for simplicity). This makes it hard for me to trace down any errors.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>          
#include <mswsock.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

my_raw_socket() {
WSADATA wsd;
SOCKET sock;
ADDRINFO* ressrc = NULL;
ADDRINFO  hints = { 0 };
ADDRINFO* multicastAddr;
char* multicastIP;
char* multicastPort;

char c_IP[] = "ff02::1";
char c_Port[] = "56333";

multicastIP = c_IP;
multicastPort = c_Port;

WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsd);   

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_flags = ((multicastIP) ? 0 : AI_PASSIVE);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;


getaddrinfo(multicastIP, multicastPort, &hints, &ressrc);
sock = socket(ressrc->ai_family, SOCK_RAW, ressrc->ai_protocol);
bind(sock, ressrc->ai_addr, ressrc->ai_addrlen);

/* Resolve the multicast group address */
hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
getaddrinfo(multicastIP, NULL, &hints, &multicastAddr);

struct ipv6_mreq multicastRequest;
memcpy(&multicastRequest.ipv6mr_multiaddr,
    &((struct sockaddr_in6*)(multicastAddr->ai_addr))->sin6_addr,
    sizeof(multicastRequest.ipv6mr_multiaddr));
multicastRequest.ipv6mr_interface = 0;

setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&multicastRequest, sizeof(multicastRequest));    

freeaddrinfo(ressrc);
freeaddrinfo(multicastAddr);

u_long nonblocking_enabled = TRUE;
ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &nonblocking_enabled);

SOCKADDR_STORAGE    safrom;
char                buf[MAX_PACKET];
int                 fromlen;

while (1)
{
    fromlen = sizeof(safrom);
    if (recvfrom(sock, buf, MAX_PACKET, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&safrom, &fromlen)<0)     
    {
        //No Massege
    }
    else
    {
        //Massege
    }   
}


closesocket(sock);
WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: Your application needs to join the multicast group in order to receive traffic for that group. MLS is needed in order to tell a snooping switch to send the group traffic to your switch interface, and your NIC will reject any traffic not destined to multicast groups you have not joined. Joining a group will deal with both of those.

Comment: @RonMaupin, i thought the line setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&multicastRequest, sizeof(multicastRequest)); would join a group. will it not?